# How can I set the dimensions of a picture/image in terms of the page/margin/column dimensions in MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

In Microsoft Word 2010, when I insert an image, I can change its dimensions in the window below.

[image]

The prompt is in dutch, but the items marked in yellow translate to ‘Relatively [ ] with respect to [Margin]’. I suspect the height and width of a picture can be set to a percentage of the margin/page/columns dimensions. This is what I'm looking for, but since it's grayed out, I can only set the width manually by entering an absolute number, which is difficult to find or calculate.

Why are the height/width options with respect to the dimensions of another item disabled? How can I enable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, pictures like images you get from the web don't have the options you are seeking and thus you cannot enable them.

**Reason**

That dialogue box shares its options with pictures and shapes. Some options are available for both, but few are exclusive to either of them. The `relative height` and `width` are exclusive only to shapes (the ones created in Word, such as rectangles and WordArt).

**Solution**

Therefore, as a workaround, insert a rectangle with coloured borders and empty fill, then apply whatever measurement from that dialogue box. Now you can use this shape as a template to match the size for any picture in your document. As a suggestion, use a new document to do this so you won't mess around with any important text.